# Sending a RAW data POST-request with an HTML Form?

Tags: html, post, forms

I need to send raw data in the body of a POST request to a Webservice. Can I accomplish this with a HTML form?

Using a standard HTML input field seems to unavoidably generate a POST body of the form `<name_of_input_field>=<DATA>` whereas I would simply like to post `<DATA>`.

Do I need to resort to performing this request with javascript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can I accomplish this with a HTML form?

No.

A form can send either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data data.

If you want to use a different data format you have to start looking at JavaScript and XHR (and be subject to the Same Origin Policy and so on).

You would be better writing your server side code to accept one of the above encodings instead — there are no shortage of libraries that can decode them.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a feasible change to make at the moment. The backend is wrapped up pretty tightly with SpringMVC, using @RequestBody for input in certain cases.

Answer (score 4):

There is a potential hack here. If your data either has a natrual "=" in it, or you can modify it so that an "=" can be added in some harmless way, you can:

- Set the forms enctype to text/plain
- Set a hidden input w/ a **name** taken from the start of your
  your data, up to but excluding the first "="
- Set the input fields **value** to the byte that follows 
  the "=" until the end of the data.

Source where I learned about this technique:

https://systemoverlord.com/2016/08/24/posting-json-with-an-html-form.html

Comment: That's super clever! One issue I hit; for IE, it has a bug where `name`s are still URI encoded when using that `enctype` (`value`s correctly aren't). You're better off using the value for your data and no name and chop it off on the server if you can. Either way you need a little server code supporting IE, you'd need to decode everything before that first `=` if not cutting it

Comment: I presume you wrote javascript to read the input `text field` (/`textarea` ?) value. How did the javascript obtain it - did you give the field an `id` ?  would that not then alter the form data?

Comment: I followed your instruction. According to `chrome developer tools | Network|Headers|Form Data` the `hidden` form field name (I used `json` for the hidden field) still shows up:  `json: { "eventType": "person_sopId", "badgeId" : 7, "sopId": 100 }'`   The desired result has *just* the _json_ payload and not the _name_ = `json` included