# How to get data from the client to the server (without url parameters) in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm, server

**Besides passing data trough the url parameters**, how can I get data from, a form in the client index.html to my server.js file in Node.js?

I know how to get the data from the server to the client, but without using url parameters, I don't know how to do it the other way (client to server).

Comment: POST or AJAX. Is there a catch or you just have never heard of these?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665510/sending-a-raw-data-post-request-with-an-html-form

You basically have to maken an XMLHttpRequest using JavaScript. Using an HTML Form alone won't cut it

Comment: @Neutrosider — "Using an HTML Form alone won't cut it" —Yes it will. *This* question isn't asking for a plain text request  body.

Comment: @Quentin
As the answer in the linked question sais: "A form can send either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data data.". But you want to send data with the mine-type `text/plain`, so you should make an XHR

Comment: @Neutrosider — I don't want to sent text/plain data. **This** question doesn't ask for text/plain data.

Comment: @Quentin i was sure i read plain text somwhere on this page, but can't find it now O.o

either way, you should still use XHR, as these will allow you to correctly specify the type of data you want to send, and allow you to just set the request-body.

Comment: XHR is often needlessly complicated when a plain form will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three common ways to pass data to an HTTP server:

1. The URL
2. The request body (e.g. in a POST or PUT request)
3. Custom HTTP headers

The specifics of how you access them will depend on what libraries you are using to build your HTTP server.

e.g. to read an application/x-www-form-urlencoded HTTP request body (i.e. what you get from `<form method="POST">`) with Express.JS, you would use something like:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.username); // For <input name=username>
  res.send('POST request to homepage');
});
```