# Redirect to URL with raw post data

Tags: javascript, php, html, http, forms, http-post

My question is the same as this one: [Sending a RAW data POST-request with an HTML Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665510/sending-a-raw-data-post-request-with-an-html-form) with one exception: None of the given answers will work in my situation.

I need to communicate with a 3rd party API over which unfortunately I have no control. Mostly this takes place server side, so I communicate via CURL in my PHP script.

However, there is one place where I'm running into a wall. My server receives a redirect URL from the API which I must redirect the *user* to. As in, they must visit that 3rd part page in their web browser.

Seems easy enough, just use PHP to send the user a redirect header right? Turns out I can't do that because the 3rd party page requires POST data in the request header.

My next thought was to create an HTML form with hidden inputs and submit it to the 3rd party page. That's not working either, because the POST data I have to send is literally just a raw string, not a form field. Example: `3d2c993f-1a99-4078-bb56-c10498c65092`. Essentially I need to get rid of the 'name=' part of the POST request.

The only way I could find to send raw post data client-side was through a Javascript XMLHttpRequest. However, that's also not what I need because the user actually has to load and interact with the page at the 3rd party url in their browser.

So, I need some way to redirect my user to a 3rd party URL, including a raw string in the POST header. Anyone have any clue how to do that? I really don't care if this is done via PHP, HTML, or Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I haven't done in a long time, but PHP'S native `stream_context_create` function is the way to go.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

That, combined with a redirect header will get you on your way

Comment: If I understand what you're suggesting correctly, you're recommending I fetch the 3rd party page myself and send it to the user, rather than trying to redirect the user to the 3rd part page? Worth a shot I guess, I'll see if that will work.